# Unable to execute the query in SQL Command Prompt

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to execute the following PL/SQL query but unable to do so. The SQL Command Prompt is showing the error at the last line

Error:

```
ENCOUNTERED THE SYMBOL ";" WHEN EXPECTING ONE OF THE FOLLOWING : IF.
```

Code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON     
SET VERIFY OFF     
DECLARE    
v_reg registration%ROWTYPE;     
v_totalscore NUMBER;    
BEGIN  
v_reg.registrationid :='&registrationid';    
v_reg.studentid := &studentid;    
v_reg.courseid := '&courseid';    
v_reg.projectscore := &projectscore;    
v_reg.assignmentscore := &assgnscore;    
v_reg.internalscore := &internalscore;    
v_reg.semesterscore := &semesterscore;    

IF NOT v_reg.projectscore BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid project score');    
ELSIF NOT v_reg.assignmentscore BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid assignment score');    
ELSIF NOT v_reg.internalscore BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid internal score');    
ELSIF NOT v_reg.semesterscore BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid semester score');    

ELSE    
v_totalscore:=v_reg.projectscore+v_reg.assignmentscore+v_reg.internalscore+v_reg.semesterscore;    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student id'||v_reg.studentid);    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Course id : '||v_reg.courseid);    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total score : '||v_totalscore);    
END IF;    
END;
```

Following is the table structure of the registration table referred for the code above.

```
CREATE TABLE registration (    
registrationid NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_registration_registrationid PRIMARY KEY,    
studentid NUMBER CONSTRAINT fk_registration_studentid REFERENCES student(studentid),    
courseid VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT fk_registraiton_courseid REFERENCES course(courseid),    
projectscore NUMBER(3),    
assignmentscore NUMBER(3),    
internalscore NUMBER(3),    
semesterscore NUMBER(3),    
grade Varchar2(2)    
);
```

I'm new to SQL and Run Sql using Command Prompt, I didn't type the code for creating the table, is that the probable cause ?

Comment: Why tag SQL Server for Oracle code?

Comment: Everything's allright on my side - can you please precise the error a bit ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/hibh8qmf7/

Comment: @Emmanuel http://postimg.org/image/hibh8qmf7/

Comment: Is there no line number that comes with the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the image you show, the fact that you did not create the table yet is indeed the cause of the error: the 1st error shown is about REGISTRATION not defined yet. Try to define it first and re-run the PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this and I think the problem maybe that you are missing a / at the end of your script. This means that when you run it (i.e. hit f8 in the command window ), nothing happens. I'm guessing now, but if you then add a ;, and hit f8 again, you get the error you describe. If you add the / beneath the

`end;`

to get

`end;

/`

when you hit f8 in the command window, it should run correctly.

Comment: No that's not what I've been doing. Refer this screenshot. http://postimg.org/image/hibh8qmf7/ Except for the error in Line 22 in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE which should be DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, what is the problem in the code ?